# What is the proper way to to automatically reboot a Windows Server?

Tags: windows, automation, reboot

I started this little venture maybe 15-20 years ago. All Windows Servers need to be rebooted every other week to keep them running right. I started out using a little utility called "Power Off" to schedule reboots on Sundays. It got to be too big of a pain. Mondays were horrible. The servers rebooted but there were several problems. Something about automatically rebooting that is different from the normal *Start=>Shutdown=Restart*. So many problems I gave up and went back to manually rebooting them.

Fast forward 20 years.... I started using a MSP program called Ninja. It has a feature to reboot at a given time. I tried it and nothing has changed. Mondays are horrible. Backups don't run, VSS errors, DNS fails to start, etc, etc. The fix is the same. I have to to a Start=>Shutdown=>Restart to get things working right again.

So.... am I the only one that wants to automate the rebooting of Servers? Why isn't there a way to do an automated *Start=>Shutdown=>Restart* when things actually come back properly?

Comment: `shutdown /r` (or `/g`) command to sheduler...

Comment: Why can't you use the [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to schedule the `shutdown /r` for Sunday night?

Comment: *" All Windows Servers need to be rebooted every other week to keep them running right."* I have servers that running an year without restart and it functions properly (and yes, updates are disabled since it closed network). I believe something is wrong with setup on your side, either some program misbehaving or hardware fault. Check RAM, HDD's SMART, it should work more than a week without restarting

Comment: My Windows servers have 150+ days of uptime and no issues. There used to be some in 2003 server, but with SP1 R2 all gone. Windows updates are important to prevent memory leakage. I would go with `Task Scheduler` and shutdown utility as well.

Comment: @Hardoman: "Windows updates are important to prevent memory leakage"? Ehh... if some Windows updates happen to result in reboots, and those reboots cause all services to be restarted, and the service restarts clean up _already-leaked_ memory, that still just suppresses the symptoms and doesn't mean that Windows updates _prevent_ memory leakage. That's no different from OP's "reboot weekly to make it work better".

Comment: Your base assumptions are incorrect and need to be reassessed and modified. Personally, I use a scheduled task that checks for a variety of different reboot-requiring criteria, and then reboots if these criteria are necessary. It's simple, it restarts the servers when required, and doesn't when not.

Answer (score 4):

*"You need to stabilize the patient and understand what is really going on in order to make progress." — relevant quote from Electronics.SE*

> Why isn't there a way to do an automated Start=>Shutdown=>Restart when things actually come back properly?

Because you're focusing solely on rebooting, but did nothing to make sure *things come back properly.* Fix those things, one by one, and reboots will work.

> All Windows Servers need to be rebooted every other week to keep them running right

Maybe 15–20 years ago they did. Since there is *plenty* of (anecdotal) evidence that Windows Servers do in fact run for much longer than 2 weeks without problems, that means either

- a) modern Windows Server releases no longer have the same problems that your servers did;
- or b) the problems have external causes specific to your systems, which you should investigate in case they might become more serious (such as boot failures caused by dying disks, or timeouts caused by the network being congested...)

> Mondays were horrible. The servers rebooted but there were several problems. Something about automatically rebooting that is different from the normal Start=>Shutdown=Restart.

Sounds like it depends on *when* the servers were rebooted.

- Perhaps something on server B fails to start because it depends on server A, which is still booting – so the service is unavailable when B needs it. But when you manually reboot *just* server B, it starts fine because server A is already online at that time.
- Perhaps your network, or power supply, or storage array cannot handle *all* servers rebooting *at once* (e.g. 00:00 every monday night). When you manually reboot server B, it is fine because it's just one server and not several dozen.

Comment: If you are rebooting a server, any server, that server typically has problems that should be fixed.  Now as an Administrator, depending on the problem, you can accept those problems and perform routine maintenance.  At the end of the day, those servers, still have a problem.  *This is from a guy who keeps his personal machine up for nearly a month without a reboot.*  Which is only rebooted, to install Windows Updates, which happens automatically.

Comment: @Ramhound: But likewise, if rebooting causes services to fail, even if you stop rebooting at the end of the day you still have unreliable services and you don't know why they fail. (And they'll still fail after any _unplanned_ reboot, such as power failure.) On two occassions I had services fail to start after an automatic Windows Update reboot, but that didn't mean I had to disable reboots -- I figured out why they fail and fixed it.

Comment: Just trying to highlight you should identify the need for a server reboot every other week (unless you want to accept it).  I have servers where that is the case, they have to be rebuilt, in order to solve the underline problem for the need to reboot the servers.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is every week, every other week or every month. The same issues occur whenever the reboot is scheduled with the MSP software. All of these locations are single server so there is no order to bring them up in. Patches are the number one reason for rebooting and if you don't patch your system lord help you. You can schedule this MSP software to scan for patches, apply patches then schedule a reboot. Weekends are slow at at all my customers so I do it over the weekend. According to the MSP a scheduled reboot is nothing more than shutdown /r but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer would make it easy to see what was happening during and around the restarts.